# Why does this mesh deform when I go into object mode?

Tags: mesh

So I am making this mesh in blender and theres a weird deformation near the neck. It doesnt appear in edit mode but when I switch to object mode it appears. It looks like an error that would occur if I modeled the head seperately and joined it to the body mesh but I didn't model it seperately. Hers some images to help you out.

[image: object mode]

[image: edit mode]

Comment: that's smooth shading shows the meshes overlap since there two separate, disable it and see if it disappear

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: so switched to flat shading but still look the same, can you add the screenshot